# What does the light bulb mean on staff?

Tags: dave-the-diver

What does it mean when a staff member has a light bulb on their portrait? It also shows up under the training menu.

Staff Menu:
[image: Raul]

Training Raul:
[image: Raul with a light bulb]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you see a staff with a lightbulb above their heads, it means that you’ll get something the next time you level them up. You’ll either get **a new skill or a new recipe** after training them enough.

Source [here](https://sirusgaming.com/dave-the-diver-staff-light-bulb-what-it-means/).